# Директива препроцессора

Tags: c#

Корректно ли будет использование такого кода?

```
#define LOGGING
 #if LOGGING     
   using log4net;    
   using log4net.Config;    
 #endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В смысле компилируемости -- да, корректно: http://ideone.com/b7jxl0

Answer (score -2):

Некорректно, так как директива объявлена, не задано значение, а как раз на это значение и проверяется в if LOGGING. Надо заменить на #ifdef LOGGING, либо на #define LOGGING 1

Comment: Ну обычные куски кода работают, наличие считает за истину:)
Подкскажите, а из исопльняемого кода я могу меня значение этой директивы?

Comment: Менять не сможете, эти директивы используются только на этапе компиляции.

Comment: Вы часом не спутали с C++? В C# нету `#ifdef`.

Comment: > Подкскажите, а из исопльняемого кода я могу меня значение этой директивы?

У вас неправильное представление о директивах, прочитайте [здесь][1], например. 

[1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CF%F0%E5%EF%F0%EE%F6%E5%F1%F1%EE%F0_%D1%E8